# What happens when one reaches the center of the universe?

Tags: no-mans-sky

In No Man's sky, what happens when one reaches the center? anything significant?

Comment: The game is currently unreleased so there is only speculation. There's also a day one patch which changes a lot of things.

Comment: indeed, I added the question with the thought that maybe someone knew. Is there a speculations cheat sheet available somewhere?

Comment: I'd speculate that nobody would bother to collect a "speculations cheat sheet", because it'd be full of speculations. And nobody cares about speculations.

Comment: If you're looking for leaks you can find some here: https://www.reddit.com/r/NoMansSkyTheGame/comments/4w9sfw/all_the_game_play_leaks_in_one_single_post/

Comment: The game was also wiped for release day, so anything that people may have found before then has been lost, and potentially changed.

Comment: game is now released, this question can be reopened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a few cinematics you are sent into a new galaxy. Other than that, nothing really special shows up.  [The uploader goes into more detail here](https://www.reddit.com/r/pcgaming/comments/4x5otx/the_real_reason_sean_murray_is_telling_people_to/d6cxodu):

> As far as I can tell, going to the center of the galaxy just takes you
>   to a new galaxy. The new galaxy doesn't seem all that different from
>   the first apart from there being more expensive ships to purchase.
>   Example: near the center of the first universe, the most expensive
>   ship I found cost 18 million. Galaxy 2's most expensive ship has been
>   around 40 million. The Atlas path doesn't seem to have really done
>   anything either apart from letting me see black holes super easy.
>   Apart from that, I can't tell too much difference between taking the
>   Atlas path and not taking the Atlas path. Again, I have no idea 100%
>   whether or not I missed something or if there's another trigger for a
>   different ending. This is just what I personally experienced.

The uploader's video:

Comment: A note regarding the quote: In the first Galaxy the most expensive ship I've seen so far was more than 70 million Units.